# React Native - Failed to build the app with error `app:processStagingDebugMainManifes`

Tags: react-native

I have a fresh cloned app and tried to install node modules via `yarn install` after that when I tried to run the command `yarn android` I encountered two errors.

First error: `Execution failed for task ':app:processStagingDebugMainManifest'.`

Second error: `java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)`

I think there's nothing wrong in my config since upon checking `react-native doctor` there's no possible issue.

[image]

Comment: Put your crash log in the question.